# Is it possible to single-press Tab to select and leave a dropdown list?

Tags: keyboard-navigation, tab-key

I recently switched computers from Windows 7 and very old version of Firefox (48 IIRC, there were *reasons*, but these are not relevant here) to Windows 10 and the latest Firefox release.

The one hard-trained UI reflex that I can't get used to is that in my old setup when navigating forms a single press of the tab key could select the currently highlighted choice option in a dropdown list *and switch to the next element*. Now switching to the next element requires two presses of the tab key: one to select ethe highlighted choice and close the list, and a second one to *actually switch* to the next form element.

I strongly suspect it's a Windows thing rather than a Firefox thing because Chrome displays the same behaviour, but I have no idea if there is any hope because any attempt at searching for a solution is overloaded with question about *navigation* tabs (thanks, Google `</sarcasm>`).

Comment: Alternative idea: can you use the arrows keys to navigate/select an item from a drop-down? Doing it that way only requires one tab to move on.

Comment: ...So tab moves onto drop-down, arrow to choose drop-down option, single tab to move away from drop-down

Comment: Oh, I do navigate the drop down with arrow keys! What I describe is what happens AFTER the arrow keys! You cannot use the arrow keys without unfolding the drop down, and at that point, pressing tab only closes the drop-down with the then-highlighted choice as the selected one, instead of doing that AND switching to the next field, as it used to.

Comment: Try out `Enter` for selection of the list item, IMO it is a more intuitive way to do it.

Comment: @Circeus can you provide a website? I am getting different results on my end, basically if the drop-down isn't showing the full list a single Tab works for me Win10 Firefox 107 with 3 sites: https://fill.dev/form/credit-card-simple https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields https://www.jotform.com/form-templates/test